# I'm trying to imitate this dot pagination animation using react-slick but not having any success

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, react-slick

[Dot Pagination Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyp46.gif)

Hey, I'm kinda new to this. Sorry if this is a basic question. I found a solution but it is for react-native. I'm struggling to find a solution for this. I will be very grateful if anyone can help. Whatever style i am applying is not working. THANK YOU.

```
.slick-dots {
    margin-bottom: -1rem !important;
}

.slick-dots li {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.slick-dots li button:before {
    content: '' !important;
}

.slick-dots li button {
    background-color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.3) !important;
    height: 0.1rem !important;
    width: 0.2rem !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    margin: 0 !important;

}



.slick-dots .slick-active button {
    background-color: #5251FF !important;
    height: 0.1rem !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    animation-name: dot;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    /* width: 1rem !important; */
    /* margin: 0.8rem !important; */
}

@keyframes dot {
    0% {
        width: 0.2rem !important;
    }

    100% {
        width: 1rem !important;
    }
}
```

[the output im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80rot.gif)